Suppose  is a nonempty set. Define a natural addition and scalar multiplication on$^$, and show that $^$ is a vector space
Suppose  is a nonempty set. Let $^$ denote the set of functions from  to .
Define a natural addition and scalar multiplication on $^$, and show that $^$
is a vector space with these definitions.
so to start by defining natural addition
$(f+g)(x)= f(x)+g(x)$
and
$(\lambda g)(x)= \lambda g(x)$
the conditions a vector space must satisfy are

commutativity

$f(x)+g(x)= g(x)+f(x)$
by the natural definition of addition

associativity

let's define 3 functions $q(x), p(x), r(x)$
by the definition of addition $(q(x)+p(x))+ r(x)=q(x)+(p(x)+r(x))$
3)the additive identity
let $f(x)=0$
then we have $0+g(x)=g(x)$

additive inverse

let $f(x)=-g(x)$
then we have $f(x)+g(x)=0$

Multiplicative identity

let $g(x)=1$
then we have $g(x)f(x)=f(x)$
the distributive property follows similarly
this is  problem 7 in exercise 1B of axler 4e
thus $V^S$ is a vector space
is that right?

Yes, nothing wrong here. Here you can find solutions to the exercises in the book.
